# Can Spring Security detect current session is not consistent with user

Tags: session, spring-security

I'm now using spring security, I have such scenario in my web application:

step 1: login with user-A, and opens a page with two browser tabs

step 2: user-A logout in tab one, and do nothing to tab two

step 3: login with user-B, open the same page in tab one (note now sessionId should be user-B's)

step 4: send an ajax request in tab two

My config is like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/index").permitAll()       
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")            
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login-error");    

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1").password("pass").roles("USER")
                .and()
                .withUser("user2").password("pass").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

/login: login page url

/user/index: business page url

The expected result is, this request int step 4 should be blocked by backend(like return a 401), reminding him to re-login.

But the actual result is: this request is returned, with user-B's data.

So how to acheive the expected result by spring security?

Seems this question may not be fully associated with Spring Security, I update this question as a more general question:
How to achieve the expected result in Step 4? Doe it need to save session info in session storage or html?

Comment: That is not a Spring Security problem. Browsers are sharing cookies over all tabs. Some browsers (e.g. E) allow to open a new browser session in a new browser window to fix that problem. Some servers allow to append session ID to the URL as  a query parameter to fix that problem.

Comment: Another way is to use Spring Session.

Comment: Sorry, you said "Some servers allow to append session ID to the URL as a query parameter", I wonder where is session ID saved in client? If only saved in cookie, it cannot work, so should it be saved in html/session storage?

Comment: Server returns the session ID as cookie and client is sending the session ID as cookie. It is a transient cookie, if you close the browser (all tabs) the cookie will be deleted.